# How to get 50 big numbers (ascending order) in Realm database?

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm database for my android project. I'm having a field called `invoice number` (Integer). The invoice number is stored in sequential order. But in this series, some numbers may not be there. For example[1,5,11,20,55,.......].

Now I want to retrieve first 50 big numbers in ascending order in Realm database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RealmResults<MyObject> results = realm.where(MyObject.class).findAllSorted("invoiceNumber");
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
int first = Math.max(results.size()-50, 0);
for(int i = first; i < first + 50 && i < results.size(); i++) {
    list.add(results.get(i).getInvoiceNumber());
} 
return new ArrayList<>(list);
```